# Apply aggregations only on returned hits

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to apply the `aggregations` **ONLY** on the returned `hits` ?

I would image something like:

```
{ "query": {
        ...all my filters...
        "aggregations": {...}
      }
}
```

So then if you have `size: N` the `aggregation` will only apply to those specific `N` returned documents.

I want `aggregation.doc_count === len(hits.hits)` and be the same documents.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Sampler Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html)

Comment: I tried. It doesn't return the same document than the one in the hits. I did the test.

Comment: This does work _if the results are sorted by score_. As soon as you explicitly sort the results, it's no good.